# ctags key binding doesn't work for vim

Tags: ctags

I just installed ctags for my Mac. Everything is OK except the key binding. I'm pretty sure this is not the ctags which comes with the Mac. It does generate the right "tags" file in the directory. I tried `:tag function_name`, and it works, just the key bindings like `<C-]>` and `<C-t>` doesn't work, anyone could help me out?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you could try `:map <C-]>` to see if something (a plugin, perhaps) has overwritten the default binding of that key.